# SAS/SQL - Is it possible to match data points between columns and create a new column with data entries containing the matched column header?

Tags: sql, sas

Fairly new to SAS/SQL, and have a query, I've not been able to solve. I apologies if the details of my problems are a bit vague, but due to my job I can't be too detailed about the actual data, or show the actual code I have.

I have a table that's a combination of sales data and backlog/catalogue type data. Within the sales data is a variable that informs which group the sale belongs to. Below is a table that illustrates my data and my intent, i.e creating the Group variable that states which group the sale belongs to. Is there a way within SAS to match the catalogue_code to the group columns and return a new variable that is the column header of the matched column (ideally without the underscore).

Hope that's enough info for someone to point me in the right direction.

| catalogue_code | Group_A | Group_B | Group_C | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B01235 | B01234 | B01235 | B01236 | Group B |
| B01234 | B01234 | B01235 | B01236 | Group A |
| B01235 | B01234 | B01235 | B01236 | Group B |
| B01236 | B01234 | B01235 | B01236 | Group C |
| B01235 | B01234 | B01235 | B01236 | Group B |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the commutity :-) Here is a generic solution.

```
data have;
input catalogue_code $ Group_A $ Group_B $ Group_C $;
datalines;
B01235 B01234 B01235 B01236 
B01234 B01234 B01235 B01236 
B01235 B01234 B01235 B01236 
B01236 B01234 B01235 B01236 
B01235 B01234 B01235 B01236 
;

data want(drop = idx);
   set have;
   array g{*} Group:;
   idx = whichc(catalogue_code, of g[*]);
   group = tranwrd(vname(g[idx]), '_', ' ');
run;
```

**Result:**

```
catalogue_code Group_A Group_B Group_C group
B01235         B01234  B01235  B01236  Group B
B01234         B01234  B01235  B01236  Group A
B01235         B01234  B01235  B01236  Group B
B01236         B01234  B01235  B01236  Group C
B01235         B01234  B01235  B01236  Group B
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly like intended!

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely help if you give more details. And do you really have a table that has multiple columns that each contains same value in every row? That is kinda pointless...

If there are only a few groups that wont change you can use a simple case statement:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select catalogue_code, 
        case
            when catalogue_code = 'B01234' then 'Group A'
            when catalogue_code = 'B01235' then 'Group B'
            when catalogue_code = 'B01236' then 'Group C'
            else ''
        end as Group 
            from have
    ;
quit;
```

If you have many groups, you can join groups to your have table:

```
data groups;
    input catalogue_code $ group $;
    infile datalines4 dlm='|' truncover;
    datalines;
B01234|Group A
B01235|Group B
B01236|Group C
;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
        select a.catalogue_code, b.group
            from have a
            join groups b on a.catalogue_code=b.catalogue_code
    ;
quit;
```

As PeterClemmensen has shown, you can also use arrays. You could also use hashs. Without knowing your data it's hard to say which aproach is the best.